# How to run find cmd with NSTask

Tags: objective-c, nstask

I'm trying to get the following find command to work via NSTask:

```
find /Users/user/projects ! -path '*.git*' -ctime -1
```

However I am having trouble to get the ignore path part to work. In terminal it works fine. I get the modified files of the last 24 hrs excluding the .git directories.
When using NSTask, the .git directories are not ignored, resulting in way too many positives......
I am using the following args:

```
NSArray *args = @[@"/Users/user/projects", @"!", @"-path", @"'*.git*'", @"-ctime", @"-1"];
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why dont you try applescript for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to replace the argument

```
@"'*.git*'"
```

by

```
@"*.git*"
```

otherwise find will ignore only files that are named `'*.git*'` (verbatim). Note that the shell removes the single quotes when you execute the command in the Terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You may also find it easier to do.

```
NSString *argString = @"/Users/user/projects ! -path '*.git*' -ctime -1";
[nsTaskName setArguments: [argString componentsSeparatedByString: @" "]];
```

When you debug your arguments in terminal you can do just do a copy and past and add 'find ' in front of it.

Comment: Thats won't fix the '*.git*' vs *.git* problem I had, but I see what you mean.

Comment: Right, I should have stated that as well lol. Was just trying to help you in the future as well.